# How to extract words from CSV file and store to list in Python

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
outputDatafile = open('D:\\Files\\input.csv', 'r')
outputReader = csv.reader(outputDatafile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

print "OutputReader data type:",type(outputReader)
inputData= []
//i want to extract all values in csv to array
for row in outputReader:
    inputData.append(row)
```

I have a CSV file as follows:

> name1,value11,value12,value13
>
> name2,value21,value22,value23,value24
>
> name3

I want to extract and store all items to list
eg:

```
list[0]=name1
list[1]=value11
list[2]=value12
.
.
.
.
list[5]=name2
list[6]=value21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `extend()`, instead of `append()`. The latter adds each list as an element in the outer list, the former concatenates the lists. You can also use `+=`.

```
with open(r'D:\Files\input.csv') as f:
    input_data = []
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE):
        input_data += row
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.csv` can be considered as normal txt document with separator ','.So the only thing you need to do is split the string like:

```
outputDatafile = open('D:\\Files\\input.csv', 'r')

inputData= []
for rows in outputDatafile:
    row = rows.rstrip().spilt(',')     #row is a list of strings splited by ',' of rows.
                                       #and row[0] is name1 and so on
```